Can someone send me message on Telegram knowing only my email address?
I see that Telegram is linked to a phone number.  However, you can link an email address to it.  There are people (not yet friends) that want to use it.  I am not comfortable giving my mobile number to them.
If I give them my email address, can they still use Telegram to communicate with me ?

Perhaps, you can set up a username for your account, and hide your mobile number in the privacy settings.
Then you can share your username so that they can contact you without your number
